# ¿Como saber la versión de ionic con la que se creo una app?

Tags: ionic, ionic2, control-de-versiones

Tengo que modificar una *app* que se hizo con *ionic* hace algún tiempo, algunas funcionalidades están dando problemas y me han comentado que podría ser por usar una versión distinta a la que se uso en el desarrollo anterior.

El principal problema es que al ejecutar `ionic build android --release` se ejecuta perfectamente sin dar ningún error, pero no crea el archivo *apk* que debería.

He mirado en los archivos `package.json` y `config.xml` pero desconozco que linea es la que indica con que version se desarrollo (o si existe si quiera esa linea).

Estoy usando la versión de *ionic 2.2.3*  y se que la aplicación fue construida en la versión 2 de *ionic* pero no sabemos en que versión exactamente.

<sub>Nota: si es necesario añadiré los archivos de configuración que me indiquéis.</sub>

A petición de @Cynth S.B. esto es lo que me muestra la consola cuando ejecuto el `build`:

```
PS C:\Users\andoni.alda\Desktop\app-b> ionic build android --release

> ionic-hello-world@ ionic:build C:\Users\andoni.alda\Desktop\app-b
> ionic-app-scripts build "--release"

keywords if/then/else require v5 option
[15:10:31]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.47
[15:10:31]  build dev started ...
[15:10:31]  clean started ...
[15:10:31]  clean finished in 6 ms
[15:10:31]  copy started ...
[15:10:31]  transpile started ...
[15:10:36]  transpile finished in 5.01 s
[15:10:36]  webpack started ...
[15:10:36]  copy finished in 5.22 s
[15:10:44]  webpack finished in 7.71 s
[15:10:44]  sass started ...
[15:10:46]  sass finished in 1.90 s
[15:10:46]  build dev finished in 14.79 s
PS C:\Users\andoni.alda\Desktop\app-b>
```

El archivo de `package.json` pone lo siguiente:

```
{
    "name": "ionic-hello-world",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^3.6.1",
        "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^3.6.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
        "com.megster.cordova.FileChooser": "http://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser.git",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "~2.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "4.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "~1.6.2",
        "cordova-plugin-filepath": "~1.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
        "image-uploader": "^1.3.0",
        "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
        "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^5.3.1",
        "zone.js": "0.6.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.47",
        "typescript": "2.0.9"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [],
    "description": "equAPPeal: equAPPeal",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "com.megster.cordova.FileChooser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {
                "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
                "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
            },
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "ios"
        ]
    }
}
```

<sub>He probado a instalar la versión 2.2.1 como se indica en la linea de `ionic-native` pero sigue sin crear la apk.</sub>

Comment: `ionic info` En la carpeta del proyecto, debería de mostrarte los datos

Comment: @FedericoMadoery me muestra la versión de ionic en la que yo trabajo y necesito la version ionic con la que se hizo.

Comment: Puede que la versión que ocuparon sea la misma que tu instalaste..en que funcionalidades es que tienes problemas? Si dices que el `--release` no genera APK, es porque no esta funcionando

Comment: Según la documentación oficial de IONIC, ese comando "debería" darte la versión del proyecto, si lo ejecutas en su carpeta. Por otro lado, a que apuntas con "no crea el archivo apk que debería."

Comment: @FedericoMadoery la documentación de ionic solo dice: `$ ionic info` *Print system/environment info*. Devuelve lo que tienes como dice Lombarda no la versión con la que se creó el proyecto

Comment: A lo que entiendo, que te debería dar la información de tu ionic instalado a nivel global, y la de tu proyecto (entorno). Cosa que es lógico, porque pueden ser diferentes. Como dije "debería".

Comment: ¿Has mirado en la línea "ionic-native" del package.json? No obstante si usas Ionic2 y está hecho en Ionic2 no debería haber problemas :\ 

¿Podrías poner lo que te pone el log la hacer el build?

Comment: @CynthS.B. He editado la pregunta

Comment: Estoy viendo que estás haciendo un build simple y no un build de android ¿puede ser? Esto no genera un apk, tan sólo compila los archivos que tienes.
Intenta hacer el build de Android y muéstranos lo que te sale por consola, ya que la consola no te saca ningún error ahora mismo.

Comment: @CynthS.B. No se ve la linea del comando, ejecuto `ionic build android --release`

Comment: @Lombarda Arda Aish, perdón, vale. Por acotar un poco más el problema, supongo que tendrás instalados los sdk y jdk necesarios para generar un apk. ¿Cierto? Lo que me extraña es que no te da errores y te construye todo bien, a excepción de la creación del apk.

Comment: @CynthS.B. esta todo instalado, he conseguido crear un archivo apk en una aplicacion nueva, era porque el cordova estaba algo desactualizado, ahora da errores al hacer `npm install` en el proyecto, las dependencias estaran mal o desactualizadas tambien

Comment: @LombardaArda oh, lo tendré en cuenta. Tengo entendido que si pones ^ antes de la versión de cada dependencia en el package.json, busca la versión más parecida activa. Por otro lado, puede ser que usara una versión de node/npm anterior, pero eso ya va a ser más difícil de descubrir...

Comment: @CynthS.B. mi compañero a conseguido arreglar el resto de problemas asi que ya lo hemos conseguido porfiiin

Comment: @LombardaArda ¿Qué sucedía al final con el npm install?

Comment: @CynthS.B. si te soy sincero ni tengo ni puñetera idea de que es lo que ha hecho mi compañero, pero yo me he tenido que instalar paquetes de python y luego me ha pasado el proyecto y... magia! Funciona

Answer (score 1):

Con el siguiente comando:

```
   ionic info
```

------ La salida es la siguiente ----

```
   Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.4 
   (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.10.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

    Utility:

     cordova-res : not installed
     native-run  : 0.2.8 (update available: 0.2.9)

    System:

     NodeJS : v12.10.0 (/usr/bin/node)
     npm    : 6.10.3
      OS     : Linux 4.4
```

Comment: David, recuerda que estás en Stack Overflow en español, puede que parezca fácil de entender tu respuesta pero la idea es que todo (preguntas, respuestas, comentarios, etc) esté en español.

Comment: @DjCrazy disculpa, ya esta corregido